# Grammar of despite

Tags: grammar

Q: Is my rephrasing grammatically correct?

--Each artist has their own individual style **but** all artists share a common aim.

Rephrase: Despite each artist's having their own individual style, all artists share a common aim.

Comment: This is close to proofreading, but, yes, you have used _despite_ correctly.

Comment: “artist” should not be in the possessive case.  Also, you can drop either of the “artist” through subject deletion, so: “Despite each having their own individual style, all artists share a common aim” or “Despite each artist having their own individual style, all share a common aim”.  If this is homework, though, using those will immediately make your tutor very suspicious...

Comment: @KrisW - Yes, I could have found other things wrong with the sentence, but proofreading is off-topic.

Comment: @KrisW & Kate Bunting. No, I must challenge you both on that. *Despite each artist's* is perfectly grammatical, and some would argue superior.

Comment: What @Araucaria-Nothereanymore said. [Here's the usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=despite+him+being%2Cdespite+his+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for *despite **him/his** being [whatever he is]*, showing that the possessive has *always* been the preferred choice. The non-possesive straight noun form is gaining traction, but it's still the new kid on the block.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That chart shows possessive adjective usage, not pure nouns like "artist". While I agree that the OP's sentence is grammatical, I disagree that it's the more natural way. With a pure noun it's more natural to me to leave off the "'s", but I don't know how to manipulate Ngrams to show that.

Comment: @gotube: The best "pure noun" option I could think of was just a surname *(**smith**)*. I think multi-word np's like ***the company*** don't work so well with the possessive, but [***despite smith's being***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22despite+smith%27s+being%22) finds at least some matches in Google Books. But just looking at the first page of apostrophe-less [***despite smith being***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22despite+smith+being%22), I see that 4 of the first 10 results have the apostrophe anyway. Much lower percentage than for *pronouns*, but still common.